# Fast way to read file from input stream when we know the size with low memory usage

Tags: java, inputstream

Is there any faster way to read from an inputstream when we know the size of the data?
This code that I have is very slow:

```
File file = new File("file.jar");

if(!file.exists)file.createNewFile();
String url = "https://launcher.mojang.com/v1/objects/3870888a6c3d349d3771a3e9d16c9bf5e076b908/client.jar";
int len = 8461484;

InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();

if(!file.exists())
    file.createNewFile();

PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);

for(long i = 0;i < len;i ++) {
    writer.write(is.read());
    writer.flush();
    System.out.println(i);
}
writer.close();
```

Comment: Don't read byte by byte. Use a buffer.

Comment: With buffered reader?

Comment: But it takes a lot of memories

Comment: `BufferedOutputStream` and `InputStream.read(byte[] b, int off, int len)`. Forget readers and writers at tall.

Comment: Also, explicitly flushing after every `write` isn't helping anything.

Comment: Readers and Writers are for text files. I see that you are reading from an InputStream; are you sure this is a text file? And are you sure that this text file is the same text format (i.e. ascii, latin-1, utf-8, utf-16, etc) as your writer?

Comment: what do you mean with "low memory usage", with java you kind of loses that control.

Comment: @ControlAltDel ooh thank you, that's why my file wasn't the same as the original

Comment: @Jocke if i have only 4 gb of ram and i want to use it for 8 gb file, i can't store it in my ram

Comment: Using a buffer only takes an amount of memory equal to the size of the buffer. You can control that. 8k is typical, and this not expensive in any situation. Don't flush inside loops. You don't need to create the file three times. `new FileOutputStream(...)` is sufficient to create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Buffered Input & Output Streams together with try-with-resources
(which ensures the Streams are all closed at EOJ)
Something like this:

```
try(final InputStream  ist = new URL(url).openStream ();
    final InputStream  bis = new BufferedInputStream (ist);

    final OutputStream ost = new     FileOutputStream(file);
    final OutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(ost))
{
    final byte[] bytes = new byte[64_000]; // <- as large as possible!
    /**/  int    count;

    while ((count = bis.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        bos.write(bytes, 0, count);
    }
}
```

Comment: [`InputStream.transferTo(OutputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo-java.io.OutputStream-) (Java 9+).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I didn't thought of reading bytes ten by ten or more :)

Comment: InputStream.transferTo(OutputStream)  is ok & uses 8192 Bufsize. If you want to use a larger buffer, then you still have to do it the old-fashioned way. Shame they haven't added a length argument to the transferTo(...) Method.

Comment: @DaveTheDane You can size the buffer(s) with the [`BufferedInputStream(InputStream, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.InputStream,int)) and [`BufferedOutputStream(OutputStream, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.OutputStream,int)) constructors. I'm not sure I see much value in adding a third (as large as possible) buffer.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Regarding bufferSize: I was referring to `InputStream.transferTo(...)`. `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(InputStream, OutputStream, byte[])` does something similar. By providing a byte[] you are completely in control.